# How to return distinct values from multiple joins on tables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get distinct values from Message table but couldn't succeed though due to multiple joins on tables.

```
SELECT
    UR.CHATID,
    --U.USERNAME,
    MAX(UM.DATETIME)
FROM
    USER_REQUEST UR
JOIN 
    USER_MESSAGE UM ON UR.CHATID = UM.CHATID
JOIN 
    EXTENSION_USER EU ON EU.ID = UM.CHATUSERID
JOIN 
    USER_EXTENSION UE ON UE.CHATID = UM.CHATID
JOIN 
    User U ON U.ID = EU.USERID
WHERE
    CR.[CreatedOn] >= '2019-06-4 08:30:00'
    AND CR.CREATEDON < '2019-06-04 18:00:00' 
GROUP BY
    CR.CHATID
```

This query will fetch distinct records. Since I need UserName too on including UserName I won't get the required distinct results as in USER_MESSAGE table I have Duplicate CHATIDs.

The above query returns me the following result:

[image]

On including UserName I get the following result Where Chat Ids are duplicated:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Anything you want in your result-set has to be either grouped-by or aggregated. Please post some sample data to clarify how you want this handled.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result that really help

Comment: which username do you expect to get from `U.USERNAME`?

Comment: So, in the case where you have a duplicate chat id, which username do you want to display?

Comment: Row_Number resolved the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `ROW_NUMBER` could be helpful here.  This answer assumes that you want the record with the largest `DATETIME` value for each chat group.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT UR.CHATID, U.USERNAME, UM.DATETIME,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UR.CHATID ORDER BY UM.DATETIME DESC) rn
    FROM USER_REQUEST UR
    INNER JOIN USER_MESSAGE UM
        ON UR.CHATID = UM.CHATID
    INNER JOIN EXTENSION_USER EU
        ON EU.ID = UM.CHATUSERID
    INNER JOIN USER_EXTENSION UE
        ON UE.CHATID = UM.CHATID
    INNER JOIN User U
        ON U.ID = EU.USERID
    WHERE
        CR.CREATEDON >= '2019-06-04 08:30:00' AND
        CR.CREATEDON < '2019-06-04 18:00:00'
)

SELECT
    CHATID,
    USERNAME,
    DATETIME
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```